# How do I center my buttons on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a problem with my code and can't figure it out. I'm writing my own website and can't get my buttons to go to the center of the page. I tried almost everything I think but it always goes to about 30% or 70% for some reason... The website is not fully responsive for now I will work on that later. What's wrong with my code? What can I do to fix it next time? Thanks for any ideas!

```js
function showHide() {
    var navList = document.getElementById("nav-lists");

    if (navList.className == '_Menus') {
        navList.classList.add("_Menus-show");
    } else {
        navList.classList.remove("_Menus-show");
    }

    const body = document.querySelector('body')
    const twitter = document.querySelector('.twitter')

    twitter.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        body.classList.add('linked')
    },false)

    twitter.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
        body.classList.remove('linked')
    }, false)

}
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'familiar_probold';
    src: url('fonts/FamiliarPro/familiar_pro-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/FamiliarPro/familiar_pro-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'uni_sansheavy_caps';
    src: url('fonts/UniSansHeavy/uni_sans_heavy-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/UniSansHeavy/uni_sans_heavy-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'source_sans_problack';
    src: url('fonts/SourceSans/sourcesanspro-black-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/SourceSans/sourcesanspro-black-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;

}

.container {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

._Logo {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    flex-basis: 230px;
}

._Logo img {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 150px !important;
}

._Menus ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
._Menus ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'uni_sansheavy_caps';
}
._Menus ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}

._Iconbar {
    display: none;
    background-color: #000;
}

.menu-bar {
    width: 45px;
    align-self: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 7px 0;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.toppadding{
    padding-top: 0;
}
.topbackround{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.sloganlefttextfirst{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 5%;
    font-family: 'familiar_probold';
    font-size: 200%;
    color: grey;
}
.sloganlefttextsecond{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 5%;
    font-family: 'uni_sansheavy_caps';
    font-size: 500%;
}
.sloganlefttextthird{
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 5%;
    font-family: 'uni_sansheavy_caps';
    font-size: 500%;
    color: #DCC98E;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #DCC98E;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.howitworkslefttextfirst a{
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    left: 5%;
    font-family: 'familiar_probold';
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #B9CDBE;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #B9CDBE;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.howitworkslefttextsecond{
    position: absolute;
    top: 57%;
    left: 5%;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 200%;
    color: white;
}
hr{
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
    height: 8px;
    border: none;
}
.midbackground{
    background-color: #1B1C1E;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.tutorial{
    padding-top: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: 'uni_sansheavy_caps';
    color: #DCC98E;
    font-size: 350%;
    width: 100%;
}
.tutorial p{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    color: white;
    font-size: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
.circles{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.circles > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    background: #1B1C1E;
}

.circles > div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: 'uni_sansheavy_caps';
    font-size: 400%;
    color: grey;
}
.circles > div > div > div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.circles > div > div > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
@media (max-width: 320px)
{
    .circles > div {padding: 50%;}
}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 800px)
{
    .circles > div {padding: 25%;}
}

@media (min-width: 801px)
{
    .circles{width:800px}
    .circles > div {padding: 12.5%;}
}
.circlescontent{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.circlescontent > div {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #1B1C1E;
}

.circlescontent > div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: 'familiar_probold';
    font-size: 250%;
    color: grey;
}
.circlescontent > div > div > div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.circlescontent > div > div > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
@media (max-width: 320px)
{
    .circlescontent > div {padding: 50%;}
}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 800px)
{
    .circlescontent > div {padding: 25%;}
}

@media (min-width: 801px)
{
    .circlescontent{width:800px}
    .circlescontent > div {padding: 12.5%;}
}
.statement{
    padding-top: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: 'uni_sansheavy_caps';
    color: #DCC98E;
    font-size: 350%;
    width: 100%;
}
.statement p{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: 'familiar_probold';
    color: white;
    font-size: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
.statementfinal{
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: 'uni_sansheavy_caps';
    color: #DCC98E;
    font-size: 350%;
    width: 100%;
}  /*HERE*/
.buttonbkg{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
}
.button {
    width: 320px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transform: translatez(0);
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'familiar_probold';
    color: #B9CDBE;
    box-shadow: 0 9px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 3%;
    align-content: center;
}

.steam{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 26px;
    color: white;
    background: #BD3381;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
    display: inline-block;
    align-content: center;
}

.gradient {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: auto;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    background: radial-gradient(90px circle at top center, rgba(238,88,63,.8) 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0));
    transition: all 0s ease-out 0s;
    transform: translatex(-140px);
    animation: 18s linear 0s infinite move;
    display: inline-block;
    align-content: center;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform: translatex(-140px);
    }
    25% {
        transform: translatex(140px);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
    50% {
        transform: translatex(140px);
        opacity: 1;
        background: radial-gradient(90px circle at bottom center, rgba(238,88,63,.5) 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0));
    }
    75% {
        transform: translatex(-140px);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translatex(-140px);
        background: radial-gradient(90px circle at top center, rgba(238,88,63,.5) 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0));
    }
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    ._Logo {
        height: 60px;
    }

    ._Menus {
        flex: 100%;
        background: #333;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;

    }

    ._Menus ul{
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    ._Menus ul li a {
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    ._Menus ul li a:hover {
        background-color: #81d742;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    .container {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    ._Iconbar {
        display: flex;
        margin-right: 10px;

    }

    ._Menus-show {
        height: auto;
    }
    .brandimage{
        display: none;
    }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    ._Logo {
        height: 60px;
    }

    ._Menus {
        flex: 100%;
        background: #333;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;

    }

    ._Menus ul{
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    ._Menus ul li a {
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    ._Menus ul li a:hover {
        background-color: #81d742;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    .container {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    ._Iconbar {
        display: flex;
        margin-right: 10px;

    }

    ._Menus-show {
        height: auto;
    }

    .brandimage{
        display: none;
    }
}}


/*
#0C0028
#1D5EC3
#181A1B
 */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Reff Skins</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS responsive navigation menu</title>
</head>

<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS responsive navigation menu</title>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <section class="_Logo"><img src="images/brand.png" alt="REFF SKINS"></section>
        <section class="_Iconbar">
            <span class="menu-bar" onclick="showHide()">
                <i class="icon-bar"></i>
                <i class="icon-bar"></i>
                <i class="icon-bar"></i>
            </span>
        </section>
        <section class="_Menus" id="nav-lists">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AVAILABLE SKINS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SIGN IN THROUGH STEAM</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="toppadding"></div>
<div class="topbackround">
    <img class="topbackround" src="images/awpasiimov.jpeg">
        <div class="sloganlefttextfirst">WEBSITE WITH TRULY FREE SKINS</div>
        <div class="sloganlefttextsecond">LOW ON SKINS?</div>
        <div class="sloganlefttextthird">TIME TO GET NEW FREE!</div>

        <div class="howitworkslefttextfirst"><a href="#">HOW IS THIS WORKING?</a></div>
        <div class="howitworkslefttextsecond">check how it works page or visit our YouTube</div>

            <!--<button class="btn1">HOW IT WORKS</button></div>
                <button class="btn2">SKINS</button></div>
                <button class="btn3">SIGN IN WITH STEAM</button></div>-->

</div>

<hr></hr>

<div class="midbackground">

<div class="tutorial">HOW CAN I DO IT?<p>If you want your new skins complete the four easy steps.</p></div>

    <div class="circles">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <!-- BEG Content -->
                        1.
                        <!-- END Content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ditto the above 3 more times -->
    </div>

    <div class="circles">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <!-- BEG Content -->
                        2.
                        <!-- END Content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ditto the above 3 more times -->
    </div>

    <div class="circles">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <!-- BEG Content -->
                        3.
                        <!-- END Content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ditto the above 3 more times -->
    </div>

    <div class="circles">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <!-- BEG Content -->
                        4.
                        <!-- END Content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ditto the above 3 more times -->
    </div>
    <div class="circlescontent">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <!-- BEG Content -->
                        SIGN IN WITH STEAM
                        <!-- END Content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ditto the above 3 more times -->
    </div>
    <div class="circlescontent">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <!-- BEG Content -->
                        DO THE REFERR PROCESS
                        <!-- END Content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ditto the above 3 more times -->
    </div>
    <div class="circlescontent">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <!-- BEG Content -->
                        SELECT WANTED SKINS
                        <!-- END Content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ditto the above 3 more times -->
    </div>
    <div class="circlescontent">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <!-- BEG Content -->
                        GET YOUR SKINS
                        <!-- END Content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ditto the above 3 more times -->
    </div>

    <div class="statement">IT'S THAT EASY<p>NO DEPOSITS, NO PAYMENT METHODS, NO RISKY GAMBLING, NO SKINS HOLDING</p></div>
    <div class="statementfinal">WE SAID NO TO CATCHES!</div>


    <div class="buttunbkg">
        <a href="#" class="button steam"><span class="gradient"></span>SIGN IN WITH STEAM</a>
        <a href="#" class="button steam"><span class="gradient"></span>AVAILABLE SKINS</a>
        <a href="#" class="button steam"><span class="gradient"></span>HOW IT WORKS</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your interest. I mean these lines of code. [ Class --> buttunbkg --> button steam --> gradient]

<div class="buttunbkg">
        <a href="#" class="button steam"><span class="gradient"></span>SIGN IN WITH STEAM</a>

        <a href="#" class="button steam"><span class="gradient"></span>AVAILABLE SKINS</a>

        <a href="#" class="button steam"><span class="gradient"></span>HOW IT WORKS</a>
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've got it half using flex, here's an answer sticking to it.

Firstly, you spelt `buttonbkg` wrong. Add `flex-direction: column` to it. Then like others said you will want to get rid of the `left: 50%`. On your `.steam` add your flex, and center align/justify.

```css
.buttonbkg{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
}

.button {
    width: 320px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transform: translatez(0);
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'familiar_probold';
    color: #B9CDBE;
    box-shadow: 0 9px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3%;
    align-content: center;
}

.steam{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 26px;
    color: white;
    background: #BD3381;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Nice your code really helped me! I can already see buttons at the center of the page. The buttons are now sorted vertically. Is it possible to get it horizontal? Anyway even vertical really helped me thanks!

Comment: Oh I just did it on my own thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your button selector:

```
.button {
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `.button` class you have `left: 50%;`, remove it. Also add `margin: 3% auto`
On you `.steam` class change `display: inline-block;` to `display: block;`

`margin: 3% auto`

3% -> top/bottom margin

auto -> left/right margin, auto will make left an right margin the same

Other solution would be to change your `transform: translatez(0);` to `transform: translateX(-50%);`, but I think transform is like shooting with a shotgun at a fly.